# Generate circle around certain point of a 2D matrix

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to make a height map using randomly generated values in console using c++.
I have an array [50, 50] that is initialized as all 0s.

```
matrix = new int[rows * columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < columns; k++) {
                matrix[i * columns + k] = 0;
            }
        }
```

I use a loop to generate random points in the array and store the position of those points in a vector.

```
std::vector<int> sprinklePeaks(int peakDensity, int dimension) {
    int count = 0;
    std::vector<int> peaks;
    for (int i = 0; i < peakDensity; i++) {
        int peakIndex = randomize(0, dimension);
        matrix[peakIndex] = randomize(69, 99);
        peaks.push_back(peakIndex);
    }
    return peaks;
}
```

Problem: I am trying to generate a circle with a random radius around these points and fill the circle with randomly generated values, increasing as they approach the center, my circle generation seems to have the right coordinates for the center but the distance is wrong and no values get added to the matrix.

```
void circleGen(std::vector<int> peaks, int dimensions) {
    for (int i = 0; i < peaks.size(); i++) {
        int radius = randomize(5, 15);
        int area = 3.14159 * radius * radius;
        int index = peaks[i];
        int x = index / 50;
        int y = index % 50;
        // std::cout << "Peak: " << peaks[i] << "\n";
        // std::cout << "Peak Coordinates: [" << x << ", " << y << "]\n";
        int peakHeight = matrix[peaks[i]];
        for (int k = 0; k < radius * 2; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < radius * 2; j++) {
                int distance = sqrt((i - radius) * (i - radius) + (j - radius) * (j - radius));
                matrix[x - j * columns + y - k] = randomize(10, 20);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like some code is missing. What’s the purpose of `area` when it’s not used anywhere? (Why is it an `int`?) (The same applies to `distance`.)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which demonstrates what you observe and define the desired output for that. Point out the relevant difference you see.

Comment: Further comments: (1) Declare and use a compact 2-dimensional array or, ideally, `std::array<std::array<int, 50>, 50>` or some such. That will make the code much easier to grok. (2) How about: `matrix[(x - j) * columns + y - k] = ...`? Sometimes it’s good to parenthesize things a bit. But again, errors of this sort would not happen with reasonably declared arrays, as in `matrix[x - j][y - k]`. That’s way easier to read. Let the compiler do the multiplications as needed.

Comment: Isn't there an algorithm you can use for that? I believe it's called "Brezenham".

Comment: I used this way of making an array because it is supposed to be dinamically allocated, in the example above I used [50, 50] for simplicity. As for the other values, I dont use them in the code because I dont know where to put them.

Comment: I was trying to make sure that the logic was correct before filling in the actual circle, as in, the desired points are next to the center of the circle, not actually filling it.

Answer (score 1):

First issue could be that you don't have bounds checking. I assume you should not change the matrix (and more importantly the surrounding memory) if coordinates are out of the bounds.

Second issue I see is that you calculate `distance`, but then you don't use this value.

Third issue could be that you want to **add** to the matrix cell, not **replace** the value. In line `matrix[x - j * columns + y - k] = randomize(10, 20);` maybe it should be `+=` instead of `=`. And `distance` should participate in the right-side. Or you want to replace, but only if new value is greater than the existing value.

Fourth, as Andrej in the comments mentioned, the math to calculate the index in the matrix is wrong. Should use parentheses, `(x - j) * columns + y - k`